# frequency response for a repeating 1-2-1 filter

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I'm trying to estimate the effect of applying a simple 1-2-1 filter for multiple times, and determined the residual scales. In specific, I'm trying to reproduce this plot:

[from Small et al., 2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dunww.png)

I used the scipy.signal.freqz as below

```
filt = np.array([0.25,0.5,0.25])
w, h=signal.freqz(filt)
```

And I thought that for a repeating filter, I just need to multiply h by itself for many times (since it's in frequency domain, and filtering is just convolution.)

However, I cannot get the same plot as they did in the paper. I have three major questions,

1. I thought the 1-2-1 filter is just the triangle filter, is there other way to check its response in frequency domain?
2. How to check its frequency response for a repeating 1-2-1 filter in python? Isn't it just h times itself for multiple times?
3. I have hard time understanding the w(normalized frequency) unit in the freqz output. Could some one explain to me how to convert to wavenumber as in the plot?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the paper containing the plot available online?

Comment: The link is here but I don't think it's available online. http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00382-013-1980-9 
U think it's not good to post a plot like that here? It's a very minor point in the paper, they are trying to say that their smoothing method is effective.

Comment: You asked about understanding the units.  The paper provides the context for the units.

Comment: It turned out they just divided what comes out from freqz by 2pi, and took the absolute value of the real part of the frequency response.

Comment: 400 and 2000 passes of a 1-2-1 filter!  At those numbers, the filters are pretty much indistinguishable from a Gaussian filter.  They might just as well have used a Gaussian with different standard deviations. (But that's a comment on the paper, not this question.)

Comment: Very true. But what are the parameters for a gaussian filter with similar response? My current work is using a 500 times 2D equivalent (9point weighting smoothing). If I can find a similar gaussian filter, I can save a lot of trouble and time.

Comment: See http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~kosta/CompVis_Notes/binomial_filters.pdf.old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I was not wrong. By plotting the absolute value of the transfer function, and dividing the normalized frequeny by 2pi, I got the exact same plots, and applying mutilpe time of filter is exactly mutiplying the frequency response to itself for multiple times.

```
filt = np.array([0.25,0.5,0.25])
w, h=signal.freqz(filt)
plt.plot(w/(2*pi), abs(h**400), label='400 pass')
```

[Comparison between frequency response of repeating 1-2-1 filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKqRU.png)